# 開発環境と本番環境とで結果が異なる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[trumbowyg_rails](https://github.com/TikiTDO/trumbowyg_rails)と[simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)を併用していますが、開発環境と本番環境とで出力結果が異なり、本番環境では正常に動作してくれません。

具体的には、UserモデルとPostモデルとでtrumbowyg_railsとsimple_formを併用していますが、Postモデルの方は開発環境、本番環境とも正常に動作します。しかしUserモデルの方は開発環境は正常に動作しますが、本番環境は正常に動作しません。

o ソース
edit

```
<% provide(:button_text, '保存') %>
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.input :content, :input_html => {id: 'trumbowyg'}, label: false %>
  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

post

```
<% provide(:button_text, '投稿') %>
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', label: false %>
  <%= f.input :content, :input_html => {id:'trumbowyg'}, label: false %>
  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

o 出力結果
開発環境

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_user" id="edit_user_1" action="/users/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="VUgEwgaEyI2S6MN0fNFXbho9IZKni6ppu8sp3wh3R5gCqr0Hqj1Tu6Kxsnlt8y4JKS44enIseh1p+afmOByzOQ==" />
  <div class="input text optional user_content">
    <textarea id="trumbowyg" class="text optional" name="user[content]"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="保存" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="保存" />
</form>
```

本番環境

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_user" id="edit_user_1" action="/users/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="O087YcL6Sb+cnHJYPpyjaus2l3HbL7X/C+mJ6Yb5Mglwc+xRVCLOfAhshR/DL7SJ3R2eBr5+g8Dj5BpYkIncZA==" />
  <div class="input string optional user_content">
    <input id="trumbowyg" class="string optional" type="text" value="" name="user[content]" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="保存" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="保存" />
</form>
```

o config
開発環境

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = '----'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: host, protocol: 'https'}

end
```

本番環境

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  #config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "sample_app_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
    # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => '----',
    :port => '----',
    :domain => '----',
    :authentication => '----',
    :user_name => '----',
    :password => '----'
  }
  host = '----'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: host, protocol: 'https'}

  config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ErrorsController.action(:show).call(env) }
end
```

本番環境のアセットファイルが更新されていないと思い、以下コマンドを実行しましたが結果は変わらずでした、、、

```
rails assets:clean
rails assets:precompile
```

何か分かる方がいましたら、ご教授頂ければ幸いでございます。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　開発環境と本番環境それぞれの詳細情報を追記して頂くと、回答がより集まりやすくなると思います。現状第三者から見ると開発環境と本番環境の設定がどう違うのかも分からないです。

Comment: アドバイスを頂きありがとうございます！追記するようにいたします。